# Cannot setup and run vuejs in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, vue.js

I am quite new to vue.js but familiar with laravel. Now with laravel 5.3 release, am trying to run some sample application using vue.

**resources/js/app.js :**

```
    /**
     * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
     * include Vue and Vue Resource. This gives a great starting point for
     * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
     */

    require('./bootstrap');

    /**
     * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
     * the body of the page. From here, you may begin adding components to
     * the application, or feel free to tweak this setup for your needs.
     */



    new Vue({
          el: 'body',
          data: {
          message: 'Hello Vue World!'
          }
        })
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/app.css') }}">
<title>Laravel</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">@{{ message }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Elixir Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Elixir provides a clean, fluent API for defining some basic Gulp tasks
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for our application, as well as publishing vendor resources.
 |
 */

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserify('app.js');
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

am getting an error saying  `[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: body`

any help is appreciated,

i only see `{{message}}`, instead of Hello Vue World when i run it.

Followed some tutorial here : https://asked.io/quick-start-guide--laravel-5--vue-js---bootstrap-3

Answer (score 2):

Try to put your script tag in the end of the body instead of the head.
When the script loads inside the head-tag, the body doesn't exist yet.